# why function is not defined javascript

Tags: javascript

My functions in html file doesn't work with error I have written highter. When I change it from 
funtion name(...) to window.name = function (...) 
but it doesn't work anyway and write 
"write.name is not finction"
my code

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText(id) {
        id.innerHTML = "Ooops!";
    }

    function displayDate () {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
    }

    function addField () {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
    }

    function addInput(divName){
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<br>Select File to Upload:<br><input type="file" onchange="addInput('dynamicInput');"  name="fileName">";
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        window.displayDate();
        window.addField();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="fff" onclick="changeText(this);">Click on this text!</h1>
<form action="/getimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="dynamicInput">
        <br>Select File to Upload:<br><input type="file" onchange="addInput('dynamicInput');"  name="fileName">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    <input type="button" value="Add another input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
```

Please, help!

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: `"write.name is not finction"`? Really?

Comment: You've got a syntax error at `"<br>Select File to Upload:<br><input type="file`. Look at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: If you use double quotes within double quotes you have to escape them with a prefixed backslash. `var text = "Text with \"quotes inside\"."`. Having a syntax error may (will) cause following JS to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Its `quotes` problem you need escape the `\'` and string like this `onchange="addInput(\'dynamicInput\');"` .And `window.name` is not defined in your dom

```js
function changeText(id) {
  id.innerHTML = "Ooops!";
}

function displayDate() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}

function addField() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}

function addInput(divName) {
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.innerHTML = '<br>Select File to Upload:<br><input type="file" onchange="addInput(\'dynamicInput\');"  name="fileName">';
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  window.displayDate();
  window.addField();
}
```

```html
<h1 id="fff" onclick="changeText(this);">Click on this text!</h1>
<form action="/getimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="dynamicInput">
    <br>Select File to Upload:<br><input type="file" onchange="addInput('dynamicInput');" name="fileName">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  <input type="button" value="Add another input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note you need to escape double quotes to use them within another double quotes, or use single quotes instead.

```html
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<br>Select File to Upload:<br><input type='file' onchange='addInput('dynamicInput');' name='fileName'>";
```